# how can I prove this equation using Induction?

Tags: solution-verification

How can I prove this mathematical by induction?
$(2) = (+1)^2 − (−1)^2$

and using this relation
F(2n+1)=F(n+1)^2+F(n)^2

Comment: In short, this is hard to prove without the other relation mentioned in the "duplicate question" $F_{2n-1} = F_n^2+F_{n-1}^2$.

Comment: that's the problem they don't given me this F(2n−1=)F(2n)+F(2n−1) .

Comment: i have this relation    F(2n+1)=F(n+1)^2+F(n)^2      , how it can help me?

Comment: Please tidy up the formatting. It's unclear what the equation actually even is.

Comment: For example, what is $Fn$ supposed to be?

Comment: And how does Fibonnacci come into it?

Comment: f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2)    Fibonacci   (f- they mean a fibonacci)

Comment: Please edit your question to tidy up the notation, then. It is still entirely unclear. There are typos.

Comment: maybe know it's better?!